# Get css3 working in IE

Tags: css

How do I get my css3 animations like these http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/index3.html

working in internet explorer? Please help me!

Comment: I'm affraid you will have to perform the animations with javascritp/jQuery if you need support for LT IE10..

Answer (score 2):

You cant with pure css, transitions are [only supported for IE10+](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions), you need to use javascript for this.

Answer (score 1):

Google: CSS3 IE.

First result:

**CSS3 PIE: CSS3 decorations for IE**

[css3pie.com](http://css3pie.com/)

Code for a Internet Explorer attached behavior which, that allows IE to recognize and display a number of CSS3 properties. Site includes download.

That provides support for CSS3 as much as is possible in IE. If it's not supported in that then it can't currently be done in older versions of IE.

Comment: AFAIK pie only adds support for border-radius, box-shadow, border-image, multiple background images, linear-gradient as background image, border-image and linear-gradient. But OP needs animations/transitions which cant be done with pie.